# Why is more memory being used when encoding a slice of structs with smaller length

Tags: go, memory

When using `binary.Write` for encoding a slice of structs, I encountered some weird behaviour where memory allocations in a particular path was more than I expected.

I wrote some benchmarks in the standard library's encoding/binary package to demonstrate this.

```
type Struct struct {
    Int8       int8
    Int16      int16
    Int32      int32
    Int64      int64
    Uint8      uint8
    Uint16     uint16
    Uint32     uint32
    Uint64     uint64
    Float32    float32
    Float64    float64
    Complex64  complex64
    Complex128 complex128
    Array      [4]uint8
    Bool       bool
    BoolArray  [4]bool
}

func BenchmarkWriteSlice1000Structs(b *testing.B) {
    slice := make([]Struct, 1000)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    var w io.Writer = buf
    b.SetBytes(int64(Size(slice)))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buf.Reset()
        Write(w, BigEndian, slice)
    }
    b.StopTimer()
}

func BenchmarkWriteSlice10Structs(b *testing.B) {
    slice := make([]Struct, 10)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    var w io.Writer = buf
    b.SetBytes(int64(Size(slice)))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buf.Reset()
        Write(w, BigEndian, slice)
    }
    b.StopTimer()
}
```

I ran both benchmarks and these are the results:

- Encoding a slice with 1000 struct elements

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-01:~/go/src/encoding/binary#  ../../../bin/go test -run='^$' -memprofile memprofile.out -benchmem -bench  BenchmarkWriteSlice1000Structs -count=10
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-01:~/go/src/encoding/binary# ../../../bin/go tool pprof memprofile.out
File: binary.test
Type: alloc_space
Time: Mar 9, 2024 at 3:27pm (UTC)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 1305.40MB, 99.84% of 1307.48MB total
Dropped 8 nodes (cum <= 6.54MB)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 1302.13MB 99.59% 99.59%  1304.21MB 99.75%  encoding/binary.Write
    3.27MB  0.25% 99.84%  1307.48MB   100%  encoding/binary.BenchmarkWriteSlice1000Structs
         0     0% 99.84%  1305.31MB 99.83%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0% 99.84%  1307.48MB   100%  testing.(*B).runN
```

- Encoding a slice with 10 struct elements

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-01:~/go/src/encoding/binary# > ../../../bin/go test -run='^$' -memprofile memprofile.out -benchmem -bench  BenchmarkWriteSlice10Structs -count=10
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/root/go) has no effect
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-2gb-fra1-01:~/go/src/encoding/binary# ../../../bin/go tool pprof  memprofile.out
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/root/go) has no effect
File: binary.test
Type: alloc_space
Time: Mar 9, 2024 at 4:24pm (UTC)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 905.58MB, 100% of 905.58MB total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  792.58MB 87.52% 87.52%   905.58MB   100%  encoding/binary.Write
     113MB 12.48%   100%      113MB 12.48%  reflect.(*structType).Field
         0     0%   100%   905.58MB   100%  encoding/binary.BenchmarkWriteSlice10Structs
         0     0%   100%      113MB 12.48%  encoding/binary.dataSize
         0     0%   100%      113MB 12.48%  encoding/binary.sizeof
         0     0%   100%      113MB 12.48%  reflect.(*rtype).Field
         0     0%   100%   905.58MB   100%  testing.(*B).launch
         0     0%   100%   905.58MB   100%  testing.(*B).runN
(pprof)
```

Per the benchmarks, there is a rise in total memory allocated incurred at `reflect.(*structType).Field` when encoding a slice of 10 struct elements compared to a slice of 1000 struct elements. I expected to see the memory incurred to be at worst, the same if not less when encoding a slice of structs with lesser length.
Is this change just because there is a cap on my RAM so if I scale to a 1000 structs, there's just not enough RAM hence the drop in the usage on the `datasize()` path for that case or am I just missing something obvious?

Edit: Is it comparable in this case:

```
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  792.58MB 87.52% 87.52%   905.58MB   100%  encoding/binary.Write
     113MB 12.48%   100%      113MB 12.48%  reflect.(*structType).Field
```

```
    3.75GB 76.35% 76.35%     4.91GB   100%  std/encoding/binary.Write
    1.16GB 23.65%   100%     1.16GB 23.65%  reflect.(*structType).Field
         0     0%   100%     1.16GB 23.65%  reflect.(*rtype).Field
```

Comment: How are you seeing more memory from the second benchmark? Also, the profile is a sample of allocation, and only based on the memory at the end of the test. It does not show all allocation, the history of allocations, or peak allocation.

Comment: Doesn't `alloc_space` imply the total amount of memory allocated (regardless of released) ? In that case, doesn't it mean it's the total memory allocated throughout the benchmark? Specifically talking about the `flat` column. @JimB

Comment: `113MB 12.48%   100%      113MB 12.48%  reflect.(*structType).Field` (10 structs) is greater than `~ ~% ~MB ~% reflect.(*structType).Field` (1000 structs) no? Unless I am misinterpreting these results.

Comment: those are just where the samples taken during execution lie at the end of the benchmark. They are not really comparable to each other. Look at the cumulative line above each of those for example.

Comment: I might be missing out on interpretation of these things properly. Especially the `flat`, `cum` and what those mean in the grand scheme of things. Can you draft an answer explaining them in the context of what I posted above? Will be happy to upvote @JimB

Comment: Kindly check the question for an edit. Just curious why it's not comparable in the new comparison I posted @JimB

Comment: The sample profile is from the entire program as a whole, which is not useful for benchmarks, because there will usually be different numbers of iterations, and garbage collection happens at different points. You're using the `-benchmem` flag but not showing the output from that flag -- that will show allocation per iteration which is much more useful in a benchmark scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257119/discussion-between-kwaku-biney-and-jimb).